# Writing maven plugins (mojos) in Scala with sbt

Tags: sbt, maven-plugin

I have a multi module sbt/Scala project, and I want to write a maven plugin that depends on the scala code.

For the moment, I have the plugin in a separate project, using maven (maven-plugin packaging, and deps on the scala code). I therefore have 2 projects : one sbt and one maven. So I need to build (and publishM2) the sbt one and then build the other with maven.

Can the maven plugin be aggregated into the sbt build, so that I have only one multi-module project ? 
Do I need to keep the pom.xml and "invoke" it from sbt ? 
Can I build the mvn plugin directly in sbt (what about the packaging "maven-plugin" then) ?